# Unable to use style when convert html to image and download in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to convert HTML to Image and download using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image) library, but when I apply style in HTML then it don't print anything in image, without style are generates proper image.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import htmlToImage from "html-to-image";
 import download from "downloadjs";

 export default class MyPage extends Component {

 downloadAsImage = () => {
  htmlToImage
  .toPng(document.getElementById("test"))
  .then(function (dataUrl) {
    download(dataUrl, "test-img.png");
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error("oops, something went wrong!", error);
  });
 }
render() {
return (
          <span><div
            id="test"
            style={{
              margin: "0 auto",
              position: "relative",
              height: "480px",
              width: "310px",
              backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
              backgroundPosition: "center top",
            }}
          >
            Test
          </div>
         <button
            onClick={() => {
              this.downloadAsImage();
            }}
          >
            Download {" "}
            <img src={require("../../assets/icons/background.svg")} />
          </button>
     </span>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: How does your react component look like?

Comment: @Dario - I have edited my question.